# Best way to rotate an image using SDL?

Tags: c++, user-interface, image, sdl

I am building a game and the main character's arm will be following the mouse cursor, so it will be rotating quite frequently. What would be the best way to rotate it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With SDL you have a few choices.

---

1. Rotate all your sprites in advance (pre-render all possible rotations) and render them like you would any other sprite. This approach is fast but uses more memory and more sprites. As [@Nick Wiggle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279738) pointed out, [RotSprite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_art_scaling_algorithms#RotSprite) is a great tool for generating sprite transformations.
2. Use something like [SDL_gfx](http://freshmeat.net/projects/sdl_gfx/) to do real-time rotation/zooming. (Not recommended, very slow)
3. Use SDL in OpenGL mode and render your sprites to primitives, applying a rotation to the primitives.

---

Option `3` is probably your best bet because you gain all of the advantages of using OpenGL. It's really up to you how to want to do it. It's also a possibility that you can load your sprites, perform all rotation calculations with SDL_gfx and then save the rotated versions to an SDL_Surface in memory.

EDIT: In response to your comment I would recommend checking out Lazyfoo's SDL tutorials. [Specifically, this one about rotation](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/15_rotation_and_flipping/index.php). There is also an [OpenGl function, `glRotatef`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml), which can be useful in your case. A quick search brought back [this little tidbit](http://lists.libsdl.org/pipermail/sdl-libsdl.org/2003-September/037830.html) which could also be helpful.

Comment: I think I'd like to explore the OpenGL route, however, I've never worked with it. Do you have any recommendations on a website to start on a tutorial for rotation?

Comment: I've looked at some code from NeHe, and this seems incredibly tedious to set up a rotation on an image... I can't understand it at all, any help on this topic?

Comment: I don't/haven't worked with OpenGL in a long time. Your OpenGL-specific rotation question may be a good topic for a new question. You're bound to get a much better answer than I can give.

Comment: Just wanted to add that for your option 1 (which is the most common approach), RotSprite is a great solution -- google it, its a free tool. Also to note there is an option 4: Write it yourself using matrices; see Mark Ransom's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299267/image-scaling-and-rotating-in-c-c).

Comment: @Nick Wiggill Thanks for the update. I added a link to some information about RotSprite (the RotSprite's author's site isn't working for me right now, but I may update it later). I didn't include the fourth option because it doesn't pertain to SDL (I suppose my answer #1 doesn't either, but oh well) and you already provided a link. Thanks again!

Comment: The best way to thank someone is through an upvote on their comment :)

Comment: @ZackTheHuman None of the links above in the answer seems to be useful. I have trouble understanding 3. option. I get what you mean, but how do I do it? Do you have any example code?

Comment: @MuhamedCicak Unfortunately it looks like some of the links are dead. The advice here was to use OpenGL's API, which supports rotation, and you can do this with SDL quite easily. I recommend taking a look at Lazyfoo's tutorials: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/15_rotation_and_flipping/index.php

Comment: This solution is outdated. Julian Goddard's solution is the simplest way to do this now: use the SDL_RenderCopyEx() function.

Comment: How much og this applies to SDL 1.2?

Answer (score 16):

```
SDL_RenderCopyEx()
```

has extra arguments for rotation, flipping, and the rotation center.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a library like SDL_gfx

Comment: Yes, it is right. Use `rotozoomSurface(...)` from SDL1 or SDL2:
 https://www.ferzkopp.net/Software/SDL_rotozoom/ or `rotateSurface90Degrees(...)`