# I need help on how to rotate an image with OpenGL using SDL

Tags: c++, user-interface, opengl, rotation, sdl

I'm making a game and the arm of the character will be constantly rotating since it will be following the mouse cursor. I've never worked with openGL before and I need some help getting started. If anyone knows any good websites to start learning and one that specifically contains rotation, please let me know.

I've already visited NeHe and went to that rotation tutorial but after attempting to go through the other basic tutorials, it still seems very confusing to me, so some clarification on the topic would also be appreciated.

Also, I don't know if this would change things, but I need to rotate about the player's "shoulder," so I need to know how to make the arm rotate about this point.

Comment: You could also refer to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183900/best-way-to-rotate-an-image-using-sdl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use glTranslate to move the origin of your coordinate system and glRotate to rotate around this origin. Anyway, you should probably get a book about the basics of computer graphics. 
If you are serious about this, go for [3d computer graphics by Alan Watt](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201398559).

Comment: Yeah I'll look into that. I got an image to rotate finally, but there seems to be little dots of color around the top edge of the image as I rotate. Why would this be?