# Algorithm to zoom images clearly

Tags: c++, image, algorithm, math, image-processing

I know images can be zoomed with the help of image pyramids. And I know opencv `pyrUp()` method can zoom images. But, after certain extent, the image gets non-clear. For an example, if we zoom a small image 15 times of its original size, it is definitely not clear.

Are there any method in OpenCV to zoom the images but keep the clearance as it is in the original one? Or else, any algorithm to do this?

Comment: In general, no.  Because that would require information that isn't available in the original image.

Comment: You can't get 10 gallons of water out of a 2-gallon bucket. If the information isn't there, there's no way to create it from nothing. You've been watching too much CSI.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Zoom and enhance!

Comment: You can use OpenCVs Resize Method with quality BiCubic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV has the [Super Resolution module](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/superres/doc/super_resolution.html). I haven't had a chance to try it yet so not too sure how well it works.

You should check out [*Super-Resolution From a Single Image*](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/SingleImageSR.html):

> Methods for super-resolution (SR) can be broadly classified into two families of methods: (i) The classical multi-image super-resolution (combining images obtained at subpixel misalignments), and (ii) Example-Based super-resolution (learning correspondence between low and high resolution image patches from a database). In this paper we propose a unified framework for combining these two families of methods.

Answer (score 8):

One thing to remember:  You can't pull extra resolution out of nowhere.  When you scale up an image, you can have either a blurry, smooth image, or you can have a sharp, blocky image, or you can have something in between.  Better algorithms, that appear to have better performance with specific types of subjects, make certain assumptions about the contents of the image, which, if true, can yield higher apparent performance, but will mess up if those assumptions prove false; there you are trading *accuracy* for sharpness.

There are several good algorithms out there for zooming specific types of subjects, including [pixel art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_art_scaling_algorithms#Pixel_art_scaling_algorithms),
faces, or text.
More general algorithms for sharpening images include unsharp masking, edge enhancement, and others, however all of these are assume specific things about the contents of the image, for instance, that the image contains text, or that a noisy area would still be noisy (or not) at a higher resolution.

A low-resolution polka-dot pattern, or a sandy beach's gritty pattern, will not go over very well, and the computer may turn your seascape into something more reminiscent of a mosh pit.  Every zoom algorithm or sharpening filter has a number of costs associated with it.

In order to correctly select a zoom or sharpening algorithm, more context, including sample images, are absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You most likely want to experiment with different interpolation schemes for your images.  OpenCV provides the `resize` function that can be used with various different interpolation schemes ([docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/geometric_image_transformations.html)).  You will likely be trading off bluriness (e.g., in bicubic or bilinear interpolation schemes) with jagged aliasing effects (for example, in nearest-neighbour interpolation).  I'd recommend experimenting with the different schemes that it provides and see which ones give you the best results.

The supported interpolation schemes are listed as:

```
INTER_NEAREST nearest-neighbor interpolation
INTER_LINEAR bilinear interpolation (used by default)
INTER_AREA resampling using pixel area relation. It may be the preferred method
   for image decimation, as it gives moire-free results. But when the image is
   zoomed, it is similar to the INTER_NEAREST method
INTER_CUBIC bicubic interpolation over 4x4 pixel neighborhood
INTER_LANCZOS4 Lanczos interpolation over 8x8 pixel neighborhood
```

Wikimedia commons provides this nice comparison image for nearest-neighbour, bilinear, and bicubic interpolation:

[image: Different interpolation schemes]

You can see that you are unlikely to get the same sharpness as the original image when zoomed, but you can trade off "smoothness" for aliasing effects (i.e., jagged edges).

Comment: wow. Thanks. I really appreciate your help. Special thanks for pointing out what I can try

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [quick image scaling algorithms](http://web.archive.org/web/20150218020203/http://www.compuphase.com/graphic/scale.htm).

> First, I will discuss a simple algorithm, dubbed "smooth Bresenham" that can best be described as nearest neighbour interpolation on a zoomed grid, using a Bresenham algorithm. The algorithm is quick, it produces a quality equivalent to that of linear interpolation and it can zoom up and down, but it is only suitable for a zoom factor that is within a fairly small range. To offset this, I next develop a directional interpolation algorithm that can only magnify (scale up) and only with a factor of 2×, but that does so in a way that keeps edges sharp. This directional interpolation method is quite a bit slower than the smooth Bresenham algorithm, and it is therefore practical to cache those 2× images, once computed. Caching images with relative sizes that are powers of 2, combined with simple interpolation, is actually a third image zooming technique: MIP-mapping.

A related question is [Image scaling and rotating in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299267/image-scaling-and-rotating-in-c-c). Also, you can use [CImpg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

What your asking goes out of this universe physics: there are simply not enough bits in the original image to represent 15*15 times more details. Whatever algorithm cannot invent the "right information" that is not there. It can just find a suitable interpolation. But it will never increase the details.

Despite what happens in many police fiction, getting a picture of fingerprint on a car door handle stating from a panoramic view of a city is definitively a fake.

Answer (score 1):

You Can easily `zoom in` or `zoom out` an image in opencv using the following two functions.

For Zoom In

```
pyrUp(tmp, dst, Size(tmp.cols * 2, tmp.rows * 2));
```

For Zoom Out

```
pyrDown(tmp, dst, Size(tmp.cols / 2, tmp.rows / 2));
```

You can get details about the method in the following link:

[Image Zoom Out and Zoom In using OpenCV](http://www.life2coding.com/image-zoom-out-and-zoom-in-using-opencv/)