# I want to zoom in an image in C SDL

Tags: c, zooming, sdl, sdl-2

I need to take an image m * m and return an image n * n.

I have this code:

```c
void Zoom_Filter(SDL_Surface* surface)

int newsize = 28;

Uint32* pixels = surface -> pixels;
Uint32* pixels2 =  malloc(newsize*newsize*sizeof(Uint32));

int cote = surface -> w;


double Zoom = ((double)newsize)/(double)cote;

for(int i = 0; i < newsize; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < newsize; j++)
    {
        int X = j/Zoom;
        int Y = i/Zoom;
        Uint32 px = pixels[(Y*cote + X)];
        pixels2[i * newsize + j] = px;
    }
}

surface -> w = newsize;
surface -> h = newsize;
surface -> pixels = pixels2;
```

However it does not work very well:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Your code seems OK so I think it's your algo.  There are a lot of ways to zoom, not sure which will be preferred by you.  Best I can give you is recommend a web search -- you want keywords "rescale" or "resize" and "image" and "c/c++"  like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=resize+image+c%2Fc%2B%2B).  Notice that some of the hits are right here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299267/image-scaling-and-rotating-in-c-c).

Comment: I am pretty sure they use the same algo, of course I could use bilinear to make it smoother but the problem is exactly the same when I add it.

Comment: Hi @Iupyou  -- What I have discovered is actually that your code is working fine.  Please check out the [re-creation of your code here](https://godbolt.org/z/ajG36cbeq)  -- as long as you provide **square bitmaps**  (ie: 20x20, 10x10, etc) it seems to work really well.   Non-square, may fail.

Comment: This is pretty strange, I am using it on a squared image

Comment: -- understood.   Then if you are writing results to a file, then maybe it's actually those write routines.  Testing each module separately is the way to go for many projects that do more than 1 thing.  -- Also -- non-square bitmaps (for me) gave results like you see in your "Result:" -- so, I was really hoping that was the issue -- sorry

Comment: I have verified that the image was a square with a test printf("%i,%i",surface -> w,surface -> h); And the values are the same unfortunatly.

Comment: Hi @Iupyou -- what are the original image dimensions and the final image dimensions?  I would like to try and duplicate the trouble.

Comment: I said that I have found the error but if you want : 100*100 to 28*28

Comment: -- I know you said that, and so I really appreciate you for this answer.   I just need to try it out and analyze a tiny bit more before I can put this to rest -- I really invested a lot, and it is a very interesting topic to me: I have worked a lot with image data and transformations.  Thanks again.

Comment: OK -- One last confirmation -- your code works well in square and rectangle bitmaps.  Cheers....

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.
I think that SDL has some issue when modifying directly the size of the image and the size of the list of pixels.
To make it work, I have just created a new surface.
Thank you for your help.